# I typed sudo rm -rf ~/ by mistake on OSX

Tags: macos, rm

By mistake I types this and pressed enter. It was taking a strangely long time to delete the folder I initially wanted to delete.

I pressed ctrl + z when I say this message

> xxxx$ sudo rm -rf ~/ /Users/xxx/Documents/workspace/my-folder rm:
> /Users/xxx//Library/Application Support: Directory not empty rm:
>
> /Users/xxx//Library/WebKit: Directory not empty

Did vital stuff got deleted? IF I reboot the osx will it startup ?
I already started saving my non git comited stuff

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the tilde in your path. Be safe, your system will be unaffected. Just your user-account won't be functioning properly. So either create a new user or restore it from a backup, if you have one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System-related files should be unaffected. However, there are a lot of important user-related files that may have been deleted before you suspended the command: applications in `~/Applications`, preferences, documents, etc. I'd recommend [restoring from backup](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201250) once you've recovered any remaining files that have been created or modified since the last backup.

Comment: Why should they be unaffected? He started deleting the whole boot volume. So odds are actually pretty high that he deleted system related stuff

Comment: @JulianF.Weinert that is incorrect. The command is `sudo rm -rf ~/`. Note the tilde and /Users directory in the output provided in the question

Comment: Yea, the whole ~/Application is gone maybe some part of the ~/Library as well but not sure since I don't what was in there

Comment: Doesn't matter, `~/Applications` is empty in most cases either way

Comment: @Paulus2 as in, `/Applications` is empty?

Comment: @Kellen yes. But I'm 100% sure all my app where gone as well from that left menu in the Finder. But now it re appeared.
I forgot the apps were installed in /Applications not ~/Applications

Im gonna finish saving my un saved stuff and attempt to update my mac to high siera maybe it will fill the missing files

I think only ~/Library has stuff deleted no other ~/ folder were touched

Comment: @Paulus2 That sounds like the Finder crashing/restarting. Any app bundles that are no longer there should have their icons replaced by a question mark, IIRC.

Comment: So if you really only deleted `~`, there wouldn't be a reason to reinstall the OS. You could create a new user